# parse xml using jquery ajax and geolocation

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, jquery

I want to use geolocation get my current location and it works, and then I want to parse xml which the `lat` and `lon` should be my location. But it seems like some wrong with my code here:

`url: "http://**/festivalapi.php? method=getPhotos&returntype=xml&lat=" + mylat + "&lon="+ mylong ",`

But if I use the lat and lon directly it will be all right. Like this:

```
url: http://**/festivalapi.php? method=getPhotos&returntype=xml&lat=54.911859&lon=-1.343404`
```

So I think it must be some syntax mistakes here..

Here is the whole jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayPosition, errorFunction, { enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 30000, timeout: 27000 });
} else {
    alert('It seems like Geolocation, which is required for this page, is not enabled in your browser. Please use a browser which supports it.');
}

function displayPosition(pos) {
    var mylat = pos.coords.latitude;
    var mylong = pos.coords.longitude;
    var thediv = document.getElementById('locationinfo');
    thediv.innerHTML = '<p>Your latitide is :' +
        mylat + ' and your longitude is ' + mylong + '</p>';
}

// Error callback function
function errorFunction(pos) {
    alert('Error!');
}



$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://**/festivalapi.php? method=getPhotos&returntype=xml&lat=" + mylat + "&lon="+ mylong ",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('photo').each(function () {
            var name = $(this).find('name').text();
            var url = $(this).find('url').text();

            $('<li></li>').append("<img src='" + url + "'/>").appendTo('#photos');


        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Sorry, an error occured loading the XML file');
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mylat` and `mylong` variables are being declared with `var` inside the `displayPosition()` function, but you are using them outside that function in your AJAX call. They are not set at that point, so you aren't passing them to your AJAX call.

Move your AJAX call into `displayPosition()` and see if that fixes it for you.

Comment: Build your URL as a separate variable and log it to console before your AJAX call. Is the problem that you're not getting any data withing `displayPosition()` or is the problem that your URL is broken?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to log to console..You mean like this?                                                                         `console.log("url: "+ http://**/festivalapi.php? method=getPhotos&returntype=xml&lat=" + mylat + "&lon="+ mylong ");`  If I run `console.log("url: " + mylat + mylong); ` it will display in console properly. So there's nothing wrong with displayPosition(). Besides, URL is not broken.. Thank you very much..@hrunting

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what is actually going wrong then?  Is your error handler getting called?  Are you not getting the values you expect?  Your code as posted wouldn't send the right URL, but now it seems like you're sending the right URL and getting unexpected behavior.  What is the unexpected behavior?

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't send the whole URL, because it uses my uni sever and it works well. The problem is if the code is like this `returntype=xml&lat=" + mylat + "&lon="+ mylong ",` instead of  `returntype=xml&lat=54.911859&lon=-1.343404` the application totally can't work and the console said: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`  @hrunting

Comment: What line of your JavaScript is throwing the `Uncaught SyntaxError`?

Comment: Nevermind, I see it now. You have a `"` after `mylong` in your URL string.

Comment: Gratitude!! You solved it.. I just don't know the correct syntax.. double quotation marks and single quotation marks always confused me. Thanks again.. :) @hrunting